# Android, Google Drive: Google consent screen freezes

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-authentication, drive

I've upgraded my app to the Google Drive REST API and its Java wrappers, as described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/deprecation

My code is very close to the official demo app provided by Google. I also cross-checked with other code examples I've found.

The Google Drive API upgrade itself was successful, but now there are very few users that cannot log-in anymore. The Google consent screen displays a white box and the circle is rotating. No information is displayed at all.

On the code side the app receives the callback that something failed. No further information. No chance to debug Google's consent dialog.

What's going on here?

[image]

Comment: You can check my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68890537/oauth-consent-screen-is-blank-and-loading-icon-keeps-spinning-forever-in-android/69252934#69252934

Answer (score 0):

The issue is on Google's side. The consent dialog freezes when the e-mail address of the Google account ends with "googlemail.com". The user has to migrate to "gmail.com" and everything works fine.
https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/googlemail/rebrand

Comment: The provided link is forbidden

Comment: Seems that the link only works for old e-mail addresses that where created with "googlemail.com" in the past. The link will not work for e-mail addresses that already started with "gmail.com".