# OAuth consent screen is blank and loading icon keeps spinning forever in android app,

Tags: android, android-studio, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I have created an Android app in which I am accessing google calendar.
It was working fine a week ago but now it is not showing up the OAuth consent screen, the white popup appears with the loading icon and it keeps spinning. See the screenshot

[OAuth consent screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjHWh.png)

The error I got is

```
[com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthIOException: needremoteconsent]
```

​​After getting the exception I start the intent like this

```
startActivityForResult(
((UserRecoverableAuthIOException) mLastError).getIntent(),
Conn_frag_google.REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
```

but the OAuth consent screen is not showing up, the loading sign keeps spinning forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem with [Google Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/consent/edit). After configuring *OAuth consent screen*, adding "right scope" and wait while Google verify my changes the "UserRecoverableAuthIOException: NeedRemoteConsent" is gone and all start to work!

**UPDATE:** it will work also with "Publishing status: Testing"

Comment: Thanks for your answer.