# OAuth2 Google Fit Consent Screen Infinite Loading

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I'm interested in trying out the Google Fit API on Android to get some data from sensors, but I can't test it out due to the OAuth2 screen loading infinitely.

What I've done:

- Enabled the Google Fit API on the automatic Firebase-generated Google Cloud project that is related to the app.
- Have properly set up the app name, SHA1 fingerprint hash, and package name.
- Have set up the OAuth2 screen with my email being one of the testers and appropriate scopes added.
- Enabled the Google Sign-In method on the Firebase console, added both my SHA1 and SHA256 fingerprints, ensured my support email was selected in the Firebase project settings and replaced the google-services.json file in my project.

This is the code where I'm trying to get the user's permission for their Fitness data:

```java
    GoogleSignInOptionsExtension fitnessOptions =
                FitnessOptions.builder()
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_SLEEP_SEGMENT, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE, FitnessOptions.ACCESS_READ)
                        .build();

        GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            permissionUtil = new PermissionUtil(requireContext());
            permissionUtil.requestFitPermissions();

            googleSignInAccount = GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(requireContext(), fitnessOptions);

            if (!GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(googleSignInAccount, fitnessOptions)) {
                GoogleSignIn.requestPermissions(Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()),
                        GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE,
                        googleSignInAccount,
                        fitnessOptions);
            } else {
                accessGoogleFit();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_moods, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode == GOOGLE_FIT_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                accessGoogleFit();
            }
        }

        private void accessGoogleFit() {
            Fitness.getSensorsClient(requireContext(), GoogleSignIn.getAccountForExtension(requireContext(), fitnessOptions))
                    .findDataSources(
                            new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                                    .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM,
                                            DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA,
                                            DataType.TYPE_SLEEP_SEGMENT,
                                            DataType.TYPE_ACTIVITY_SEGMENT,
                                            DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
                                    .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
                                    .build())
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<List<DataSource>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<DataSource> dataSources) {
                            for (DataSource i : dataSources) {
                                Log.d(TAG, i.getStreamIdentifier());
                                Log.d(TAG, i.getDataType().getName());
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Find data sources request failed", e);

                        }
                    });
        }
```

It's basically the same issue that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57831466/google-drive-consent-screen-stuck) thread is talking about.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you found any solution im facing the same issue

Comment: Does your application on the Google Cloud Console have "Verification in progress" as verification status?